# OData using PageResult missing GetNextPageLink and GetInlineCount extension methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to implement OData to respond with JSON as a quick and easy way of doing some filtering/paging of results with Web API.

However as total counts aren't supported I'm using PageResult as per the 2nd half of [this asp.net article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#server-paging).

But the extension methods `GetNextPageLink` & `GetInlineCount` don't seem to exist. I've got `using System.Web.Http.OData` but they're just not appearing!

I can't seem to find them in the object browser either.

Where are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found them in the `System.Net.Http` namespace. And they're deliberately hidden from the object browser.

You have to add a `using System.Net.Http` to use them.

Strange place to put them.

Comment: They hang off `HttpRequestMessage`. So, the thinking is that you would have a `using System.Net.Http` already which makes them be ready through intellisense when you press that `.`.

Comment: @RaghuRam well the thinking is wrong, I didn't have a `System.Net.Http` reference. It was a brand new blank project that I'm using to 'strangle' a terribly written VB project. They've made a colossal mess with the WebAPI so far, I keep hitting issues like this using it. Another example recently was the mess they've made of routing, it's not the same as the existing way, so everything has to be duplicated. They're just badly thought out and horrible to use in existing projects.